# В чём отличие contacts.db от contacts2.db?

Tags: android

> Контакты *Android* хранятся в директории
>   /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/ в файле
>   **contacts.db** или на некоторых прошивках **contacts2.db**.

И я хочу узнать: отличаются ли чем-нибудь эти файлы, **contacts.db** и **contacts2.db**?